# Dynamic memory allocation in c arrays of structs

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

```c
void addWorkerToProject(Worker *worker, Project *project) {
    worker->projects =  malloc(sizeof (strlen(project)+1));
    worker->projects[worker->projectCount]->name =  project->name;
    worker->projectCount++;
}

    struct Worker

    char *name;
    Project **projects;
    int projectCount;

    struct Project

    char *name;
    Worker **workers;
    int workerCount;
    FeatureNode *features;
```

How do I make this function run correctly? It supposed to assign workers to project, but it fails to assign 2 projects to the same worker.

Let's say I have a worker named Sean and two projects name first and second. I need to attach them to Sean so for example when I print workers[i]->projects[j]->name they both needs to appear, when each iteration adds him 1 project. When I run it the first iteration is correct but the second one doesn't work.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and describe "run correctly" (for example, how the data should be set).

Comment: `(strlen(project->name) + 1) * sizeof(Project*)` makes no sense. Why do you want to multiply the string length with the size of a pointer (which will likely always be `8`)? And if you want to copy a number of `Project` structures, you need a loop.

Answer (score 1):

`malloc(sizeof (strlen(project)+1))` will always return size of an integer. i.e.4 bytes/8 bytes based on your machine/os.
What I felt you are trying to do is as below:

```
void addWorkerToProject(Worker *worker, Project *project) {
    worker->projects[worker->projectCount] =  malloc(sizeof(Project));
    worker->projects[worker->projectCount]->name = project->name;
    worker->projectCount++; 
}
```